# How to add custom field type on KeystoneJS 0.4?

Tags: keystonejs

I'm currently building an app for TV/Radio program guide and schedule using keystonejs. I need time input field (hour and minute) for it to work. By default keystonejs doesn't give me an option of time field. Only Date and Datetime are available, none of which are suitable for my use case. Keystonejs documentation doesn't really do the job for `>0.4`. Although, I can spare its sparse documentation since it's still in beta phase

1. <s>How to create a new Field type which is usable in production app on keystonejs 0.4.3-beta without directly modifying keystonejs node_modules package?

   The one that I found on keystonejs wiki (credit card field type), is to create custom field for development only. And it doesn't even translate to admin UI.</s>
2. Is it possible to add plugin (such as npm clock-input) to use it as field input on keystonejs admin UI?
3. I'm still thinking of the best way to integrate schedule system in keystonejs admin UI. For now, I'm thinking of creating a List which contains program name, description, days of the week, and time. In this case, some TV program are supposed to be able to have multiple days, and on specific days of the week it has different time (for example: **program A** being aired from Monday-Thursday on 4PM, and Friday on 7PM).
   I think the way I'm currently planning to implement on is a bit messy. Any suggestion of the good way to do this?

*note:
I figure #1 out, although I'm still learning on how it actually works.
I ended up using `keystone-custom-fieldtypes` npm packages to export my custom input field to keystonejs module without manually touching the file (I use igorrafael fork which works for `keystonejs >0.4`. Since the original package only works for keystonejs 0.3). You can find it here : https://github.com/igorrafael/keystone-custom-fieldtypes.

I managed to duplicate one of the default field type. So currently I have my custom field type boilerplate. Still need to modify a lot of things though.*